# python - error happens when using super()

Tags: python, super

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import datetime

db = SQLAlchemy()

class BaseModel(db.Model):
    """Base data model for all objects"""
    __abstract__ = True

    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(self).__init__(*args)

    def __repr__(self):
        """Define a base way to print models"""
        return '%s(%s)' % (self.__class__.__name__, {
            column: value
            for column, value in self._to_dict().items()
        })

    def json(self):
        """Define a base way to jsonify models, dealing with datetime objects"""
        return {
            column: value if not isinstance(value, datetime.date) else value.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
            for column, value in self._to_dict().items()
        }


class Station(BaseModel, db.Model):
    """Model for the stations table"""
    __tablename__ = 'stations'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    lat = db.Column(db.Float)
    lng = db.Column(db.Float)
```

> TypeError: super() argument 1 must be type, not Station

I know super with no argument is only used in python3. but in my case what should i fill in the super()? Also is it okay to put the super() in init of the father class(basemodel)?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're not *doing* anything in `BaseModel.__init__`, the correct approach is to not implement it at all. Without `__init__` defined in `BaseModel`, you'll go to the super class's `__init__` automatically, and more efficiently.

That said, if you *are* doing something meaningful in `BaseModel.__init__`, you can't use one-argument `super` like that. One-argument `super` is of very limited use (basically, only for `classmethod`s, where you're passing the type but not an instance of the type as the argument). You need [two-argument `super`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super), explicitly providing the name of the *current* class you're trying to bypass looking for superclasses, then `self`, e.g:

```
class BaseModel(db.Model):
    """Base data model for all objects"""
    __abstract__ = True

    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(BaseModel, self).__init__(*args)
```

Comment: So I still need a init in my station class? BaseModel.__init__ is only to define those things that i want the child class to inherit? also can you explain how do i pass the *args to the BaseModel.__init__ and what does it do?

Comment: @pwan: You only need a `__init__` in your class if it is doing some unique that the parent class doesn't already do. SQLAlchemy types provide a decent default, so you might not need it in any class. As for the meaning of `*args`, I suggest you read [the Python tutorial on arbitrary argument lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists) and [unpacking argument lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).